# add microsoft office chart

Tags: c#, charts, ms-office

I want to add "microsoft office chart" to my windows application. But when I select "choose item .../com component", it isn't in list.
Not bad I say that I have installed office 2007.
Now how do I can add this component.
.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en).